# Non-Negative Vs Positive Semi Definite

Tags: matrices, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, positive-semidefinite, nonnegative-matrices

A matrix is PSD if $$\langle Ax, x\rangle \ge 0,  \forall x \in H$$

Where, H is a hilbert space and A is a mapping $H \rightarrow H$. Is it the same as being Non-negative? I couldn't seem to find a specific definition for a non-negative operator.

Comment: Non-negative does not make much sense when talking about matrices. When saying non-negative , one is usually talking about real numbers, or integers

Comment: I would say they are analogous, but the notion of non-negativity for a matrix doesn´t make much sense